# Sending email to a distribution list using System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient

Tags: c#, list, smtpclient

I'm sending email to a distribution list using System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient
Here is the method I use. xyz@domain.com is the distribution list.

```
var strMailServer = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MailServer"];
var fromAddress = new MailAddress("abc@domain.com");
var bodyMsg = "BodyText;
var message = new MailMessage();
var smtpClient = new SmtpClient(strMailServer)
{
    Credentials = new NetworkCredential("", ""),
    Port = 25,
    EnableSsl = true
};

message.From = fromAddress;
message.To.Add("xyz@domain.com");
message.Subject = _context.Fields["Subject"].Value;
message.IsBodyHtml = true;
message.Body = bodyMsg;
smtpClient.Send(message);
```

The mail is not delivered to xyz@domain.com distribution list. Am I missing something?

Comment: If you change it to SomeSpecificPerson@domain.com, is the email delivered?  Could be many things including your SMTP server (whatever is in strMailServer) not accepting unauthenticated SMTP requests.  Depends on how the email infrastructure is setup.

Comment: Using the same code email is successfully sent to specific person. Just when I try a distribution list, it fails. I'm able to email that list from my outlook. So the list exists.

Comment: Can you show how you are adding the distribution list to `message.To`?

Comment: Just to check the obvious...if you send to this distribution list from your normal email account, the intended recipients receive the email?

Comment: Yes. I can do that through normal email account. It works fine.

Comment: is exception thrown?

Comment: The line is message.To.Add("xyz@domain.com");

Comment: I enclosed in try catch block. No exceptions.

Comment: If you check the `abc@domain.com` sender account is there any bounce back email from the postmaster?

Comment: Is the @domain.com from sender and from the list the same? some list block e-mails from other domains.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When creating the distribution list, uncheck "Require that all senders are authenticated"

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a username and password other than your windows credentials, you need to set `UseDefaultCredentials` to false **before** providing the new credentials:

```
var smtpClient = new SmtpClient(strMailServer)
{
    UseDefaultCredentials = false,
    Credentials = new NetworkCredential("", ""),
    Port = 25,
    EnableSsl = true
};
```